# Rendering EMF/WMF images in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf

how to display EMF/WMF image on WPF window.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this thread. You won't like the answer. ;-)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7010cefa-e596-45af-b193-40206451dd90/

Answer (score 1):

[Ab2d.ReaderWmf](http://www.wpf-graphics.com/ReaderWmf.aspx) does exactly what you want - imports WMF image into WPF's Viewbox.